# UITextView textViewDidChangeSelection called twice

Tags: ios, nsarray, uitextview, avaudioplayer

**What I have**  :

TextView

NSArray (string)

AVAudioplayer (not yet implemented)

**When I select a word in TextView** :

• Check if word exist in Array

• Start Audioplayer with associated sound

Unfortunately when I tap twice to select a word inside TextView, textViewDidChangeSelection is called twice. I don’t know why I see "Youpie" twice.

I just changed inputView to hide keyboard because I only need TextView to be used in selecting mode.

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)tve;
{
    NSString *selectedText = [tve textInRange:tve.selectedTextRange];
    if(selectedText.length > 0)
    {
        for (NSString *text in textArray)
        {
            if ([selectedText isEqualToString:text])
            NSLog(@"Youpie");
            tve.selectedTextRange = nil;
            if (ps1.playing == YES)
            {
                [self stopEveryPlayer];
                [self updateViewForPlayerState:ps1];
            }
            else if ([ps1 play])
                {
                    [self updateViewForPlayerState:ps1];
                    fileName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ (%d ch.)", [[ps1.url relativePath] lastPathComponent], ps1.numberOfChannels, nil];
                }
                else
                    NSLog(@"Could not play %@\n", ps1.url);
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{  
    textArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"dog",@"cat",@"person",@"bird",@"mouse",  nil];
    textView.inputView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]  autorelease];
    textView.delegate = self;
// ...
}
```

I noticed something when I was double tapping on each good word in my text.

**textViewDidChangeSelection**

If a word is already selected and no action choosen, I have 1 "Youpie".

If not, I have 2 "Youpie".

I found a simple solution. I removed selectedRange after getting value. textViewDidChangeSelection called once.

**What I have changed**

```
tve.selectedTextRange = nil;
```

I use a subclass of `UITextView` to disable menu.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

I added an implementation for `AVAudioPlayer` (ps1) too.

My "autoplay" is working if a known word is selecting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for why the method gets called twice or how to prevent this, but an alternative solution might be to display an additional item in the edit menu that pops up in a text view when a word is double clicked.  Then, your action for initiating a sound based on the word could be triggered from the action selector defined in that additional menu item.  In this design, you'd remove your textViewDidChangeSelection and thus would not get called twice. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html for some additional info about modifying the standard menu.

Comment: I found solution after dreaming. I can't believe it... Custom menu is a good choice too. I'm sure I'll use it in another case :)