# UITextView delegate textViewDidChangeSelection is called twice

Tags: ios, swift, textview, delegates, uikit

I'm trying to do some stuff when user taps Enter button, so I have implemented the following delegates for UITextView:

```
// Delegate is called when text is gonna change
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (text == "\n") {
        // Some behavior when user taps Enter
        return true
    }

    // Some other code
    return true
}

// Delegate is called when selection is changed
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    // Some code
}
```

The problem is, `textViewDidChangeSelection` is called **twice** when user taps Enter.

In second call, `textView.selectedRange` is changed to the last character of text view. This produces a problem when user taps Enter after any line in the middle of text, because caret position is changed to end of text.

I've attached a ‏reproducible example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qgststlhvfajbi/reprex%202.zip?dl=0) so you can check, I'm not sure if the problem is in the delegates, or in the way I attached the delegate to the view.

**To re-produce the problem**, do the following scenario:

1. Write some lines, for example:

   Line 1.

   Bla bla bla

   line 3
2. Go to the end of line 1.
3. Tap on Enter.

The new line is there in the right position, but the caret position is changed to the end of text view.

**Notes:**

- I've checked the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107962/uitextview-textviewdidchangeselection-called-twice) in stackoverflow, but it doesn't
  fix my problem.
- The file you need to review in my ‏reproducible example is `EditorTextView.swift`
  only.

Comment: "The problem is, textViewDidChangeSelection is called twice when user taps Enter."  What's the injury?

Comment: That reproducible example isn't very minimal.. Do you actually need the `UIViewRepresentable` implementation? Does this not happen in UIKit as well?

Comment: @el-tomato I’m sorry but I didn’t get your question

Comment: @sweeper I need the UIViewRepresentable because SwiftUI doesn’t support Attributed Strings. I’m not sure about the normal UIKit but I think the problem will happen there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK finally, I found a solution for this weird behavior of delegation in the UITextView wrapper for SwiftUI.

So the entire issue was with setting the text again every time `updateUIView` was called. That is not necessary and it caused a weird feedback loop with `textViewDidChange` delegate method (that is where I set the selected range when the last character was `\n`, which is the case for a new line).

I don't know exactly why does that happen, I just think it's a bug with how `UIViewRepresentables` works under the hood.

So, to solve the issue, I had to move the following line from `updateUIView`:

```
uiView.text = document
```

And add it to `makeUIView`:

```
textView.text = document
```

This way, it will be bound permanently.